# iMac is slow, memory pressure green

Tags: macos, terminal, imac, memory

I really need help with this one. It's extremely important, I can't afford to buy a new computer. So maybe like 3 or 4 weeks ago I got a virus. We got rid of the virus, but the computer was sill INCREDIBLY slow. It got so extreme I had to wipe the drive and install a fresh copy of macOS Sierra. This still did not make it faster. It sure helped, but it didn't fix it. I have to do frequent restarts to get mild preformance for like 10 minutes. As of time of writing, it's being very slow. I'm barely able to type.

So I asked on StackExchange, but I didn't pose my question correct I guess, so at the end, the answer was, I do not need more RAM. I want to fix my computer all the way and make it fast like it was before the virus. I ran like every command on the internet and an EtreCheck to make sure that I have all the information any of you will probably need, if I don't, I'll gladly run any diagnostic.

**Apple Hardware Test:** Passed

**SMART Status:** Verified

**EtreCheck Log:** http://pastebin.com/KN4Ad1hS

**Terminal Commands:** http://pastebin.com/Gyjm6keX
(sorry it wouldn't let me post more than 2 links, so I put the 2 command's pastebin links in one pastebin)

**diskutil list:**

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            999.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

**diskutil verifyDisk disk0:**

```
Started partition map verification on disk0
Checking prerequisites
Checking the partition list
Checking the partition map size
Checking for an EFI system partition
Checking the EFI system partition's size
Checking the EFI system partition's file system
Checking the EFI system partition's folder content
Checking all HFS data partition loader spaces
Checking booter partitions
Checking booter partition disk0s3
Verifying file system
Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume
Checking extents overflow file
Checking catalog file
Checking multi-linked files
Checking catalog hierarchy
Checking extended attributes file
Checking volume bitmap
Checking volume information
The volume Recovery HD appears to be OK
File system check exit code is 0
Checking Core Storage Physical Volume partitions
The partition map appears to be OK
Finished partition map verification on disk0
```

Computer Info Image:

[image]

Activity Monitor Image:

[image]

Please help! Thanks :)!

[image]

Comment: EtreChck shows mdworker is busy - indexing for Spotlight. Try leaving the machine on overnight & let it finish, just in case that was enough to slow you down.

Comment: I already did that

Comment: You have a late 2012 iMac.  I am assuming that you have the Fusion Drive; can you confirm?  Please issue the following commands and post to your original question:  `diskutil list` as well as `diskutil info disk0 | grep -i "smart"`.  You can copy the output directly to your clipboard for pasting by appending the `| pbcopy` to the command.  Example:  `diskutil list | pbcopy`

Comment: I was finally able to open the link to pastebin.  You do in fact have a Fusion Drive.  I am suspecting it's crashing.  Issue the commands I listed above to confirm.

Comment: I did your commands and edited them into the main question.

Comment: Try running this software:  [Disk Drill](http://www.cleverfiles.com/) (It's free).  It will do a deep scan of your disk.  I am still convinced you are having HDD issues.  Also, when replying to comments be sure to put the "@username" of who you are replying to so that it notifies the recipient you posted a comment.  That's not necessary if responding to a users answer.

Comment: I forgot to mention one command:  'diskutil verifyDisk disk0`  Post those results as well.

Comment: @Allan I posted the verifyDisk command, deep scan right now is running on Macintosh HD

Comment: What does deep scan even do?

Comment: It scans your drive for physical errors.  I am having you go through this because it's much easier than continually installing/reinstalling the OS.  Unless you changed your drive, you are using a 4 to 5 year old Seagate HDD and they are notorious for being unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

I remember your other questions, so will try and help you get to the bottom of this. You need to understand though, that troubleshooting is a process of elimination and, as a result, can take some time.

Before we start, I am going to ignore that you had a virus a few weeks ago, because that could be confusing things. In other words, we need to start afresh because the virus and this issue may be totally unrelated.

I can see from the various images you posted that you do have plenty of free hard drive space, so that's one possible cause we can eliminate. So, one by one, let's try and resolve this.

**1. Let's start your computer in Safe Mode**

Our first test will be to see what happens when you start your iMac in Safe Mode. Doing this forces your iMac to perform some tests and also prevents some software from automatically loading or opening.

Follow these steps:

- Shutdown your iMac
- As soon as you hear the startup sound, press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key
- Once you see the Apple logo, let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key

Don't be concerned if your iMac takes longer to boot up (remember it's performing some tests). After it's booted, use it for a while. Do this for long enough for you to be satisfied that the problem still persists (or not). Once you're done, restart the computer normally to exit Safe Mode.

**Note:** While in Safe mode you won't be able to do everything you normally can, and your macOS environment may appear/work differently. Do not worry about this.

When ready, report back on how you went.

**2. Create and log in to a new user account**

Our next test is to create a totally new user account and check whether logging in to this has any impact on performance. In case you don't know how to do this, follow these steps:

- Go to Apple Menu > System Preferences
- Select Users and Groups
- Click on the + sign at bottom left to add a new user (you may need to unlock the padlock below that to make changes)
- Set your user options and ensure that automatic login is off
- Exit System Preferences

Now restart your computer and log in to the newly created user account. Once logged in, do not install any new software etc. Instead, just use the computer for a while to determine if it is still slow.

When ready, report back on how you went.

**3. Install macOS Sierra on an external drive**

Our next test is to take advantage of your external hard drive to try and determine whether we have an issue between macOS Sierra and your computer. If not, it may indicate either a problem with your internal hard drive or 3rd party software.

Use this process:

- Do a full installation of macOS Sierra on the external hard drive but **do not install any 3rd party software**.
- Restart your Mac.
- Immediately press and hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key.
- The Startup Manager will appear and shouldn't take too long to list your internal hard drive and the external drive.
- Use your mouse or the left/right arrow keys to select the external hard drive you just installed macOS Sierra on
- Double-click or press the Return key to start your iMac from the external hard drive

Now use your iMac from the external drive for a while doing a few things to get a sense of how well it's responding. Please only use default Apple apps (such as Safari etc) for now.

When ready, report back on how you went.

Comment: During safemode, it was still pretty slow, preformande improved a tiny bit after booting back to normal mode.

Comment: That's actually to be expected. In Safe Mode your Mac isn't as responsive as it should be, and after booting normally your iMac should be slower for a while because starting in Safe Mode actually clears all the caches. (Caches are used by the system to make your Mac faster.) In your case you've already noticed a slight improvement - this is unusual (but good in your case). So, what you need to do now is be a little patient and use your Mac as normal. After a while (and a few reboots), the caches will be recreated and we'll get a clearer idea as to whether this has resolved the issue.

Comment: I've restarted it about 5 times now, everytime I need to switch programs basically. Then I ran OnyX and ran Automstion. After that, it's restarted a few times

Comment: OnyX is a great utility for advanced users, it's of little value to most other users. It's also very easy to accidentally remove files that are essential, so make sure you're careful using it. Also, for your caches to build up again takes time - you need to use your computer as per normal for a couple of days or so. Can you please clarify what you meant by *I've restarted it about 5 times now, everytime I need to switch programs basically.* Why? What's happening?

Comment: Well, basically I can have a program open and it works ok-ish, but then if I want to go to a different program, sometimes I have to restart to make the computer faster so I can open it. Today preformande has improved a bit aswee

Comment: For example. Today I was working on After Effects, for the first 10 minutes, it was very fast, then it got insanely sluggish.

Comment: This is good to know! I'm sorry, but to keep going I have some questions: (1) What were you actually trying to do when After Effects went sluggish? (2) Can you give me two more examples of sluggish behaviour? (3) What are the top 5 programs you use the most. (4) Do you have access to an external hard drive? (5) Did you do the new test in my answer? If so, what were the results? (6) And finally, can you update your question to include another screenshot: Go to Apple > About This Mac, click on the System Report button, and take a screenshot of the Hardware Overview info on the righthand side.

Comment: 1.) I was doing the Jelly effect 2.) Opening programs and using help in those programs 3.) After Effects, Gimp, Activity Monitor, Safari, Disk Utility 4.) I have an external hardrive, I have not opened it yet. 5.) I did Safe Mode, and it helped a bit.

Comment: Thanks. Before I add more to my answer, can you verify whether you've done my second test? Starting in Safe Mode was test 1, creating a new user account was test 2.

Comment: Making a new user account did not work.

Comment: I have just added the 3rd test to my answer. Let me know how you go.

Comment: I'm not sure if my hardrive can run an OS, is there a way to check?

Comment: If you're unsure, just connect it to your iMac and then run Disk Utility to erase the external disk using the Mac OS Extended (Journaled) format. Once it's formatted, quit Disk Utility and install macOS as you've done previously, ensuring you select the external hard drive to install it on. By the way, if you find after doing the 3rd test that everything seems okay (i.e. Your iMac is running noticeably better than it is from the internal HDD), then the next test would be to install After Effects onto the external hard drive and to use it for a while and see whether this has any impact.

Comment: The problem with using my external hard drive, is it's my moms. I oculd probably convince her, but is there any other way to check without using an external Harddrive?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed from your earlier comments that it was a brand new one you had bought for yourself. If it's brand new and your mum is going to use it with a Mac then it'd be fine to do this test, because afterwards you would just erase it again and give it back to her. But if she's going to use it with a Windows machine, then do not use it. Let me know and I'll come up with another option.